# Проблема с Multi Touch

Tags: android, multi-touch

Не могу разобраться с MultiTouch. Создал CustomView которое умеет само (не через Activity) обрабатывает жесты onScroll и onFling. Таких view будет две в моём Activity, то есть два отдельных квадрата CustomView и много пустого Activity. Необходимо будет скролить мои View одновременно двумя разными пальцами. Сейчас всё действует не совсем корректно:

1. Если почти одновременно коснуться моих view двумя разными пальцами и начать скролить, то всё работает как надо. Если убрать палец с одной view а на другой оставить, а затем снова опустить палец на первое view, то оно уже не будет следовать за пальцем. А вот если поставить на неё третий палец то за ним она последует.
2. Если поставить палец на одну из view, а второй палец поставить на пустое место в Activity, то View будет скролиться от обоих пальцев.

Не знаю куда "копать". Нужно ли как-то обрабатывать MultiTouch в Activity, или мои View нужно поместить во ViewGroup. По сути для для моих View нет multiTouch, а для Activity в данном случае есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгого изучения вопроса и экспериментов таки нашёл ответ. Следует добавить, что за реализацию onScroll и onFling в моих CustomView изначально отвечал GestureDetector. В мнём и оказалась проблема. Если реализовать scroll и fling через обычные  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN .ACTION_MOVE .ACTION_UP и добавить VelocityTracker то оба View работают так как это задумывалось - каждая всегда реагирует на свой палец.